# Unknown binaries preventing codesigning

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Earlier today, i had to reinstall node on my pc. Now when I try to archive my ionic app, I see these unkwown binaries `fse.node*, etc.` that are preventing the build from proceeding

My question is: How do i remove these **fse.*** files from this list. they were never there before, only my `.ipa`. They trace back to multiple `node_modules/` folders using the `fsevents` module

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this? It just happened to me too.